# Where does the Symfony plugin 'sfLucene' get the information about my database schema from?

Tags: mysql, database, caching, symfony1, lucene

A month ago I adjusted my database schema. I added a column called ordinal.

I rebuilt my model and uploaded my changes.

Everything works fine apart from my instance of sfLucene will not rebuild.

I run

```
symfony lucene-rebuild frontend
```

But I get the error once it gets to the Model in question (others are fine):

```
propel exception: unknown column ORDINAL
```

I have tried clearing the Symfony cache but to no avail.

I feel like Lucene has cached the database schema somewhere not sure where.

Index rebuilding works fine on my local PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem solved

The `databases.yml` file on the server had the `all:` setting pointed to my test server.

Unfortunately, the test server is on the same box, therefore MySQL login was succeeding.

However the test database did not have the recently added fields.

The command line (i.e. the `symfony lucene-rebuild` command) uses the `all:` setting in the databases.yml

Comment: Ha ha - sorry @Raise! It was most definitely all down to you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably checks schema.yml or schema.xml

You can regenerate/update it with the console command

```
symfony propel:build-schema
```

Older versions of symfony use this syntax

```
symfony propel-build-schema
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have tried rebuilding my model and it has not helped the situation.